# Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab+a+2}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc+b+2}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{ac+c+2}} \leq \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, radicals, fractions, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $abc=1$ and $a,b,c>0$.
Prove that 
$$\frac {1}{\sqrt {ab+a+2}}+ \frac {1}{\sqrt {bc+b+2}}+ \frac {1}{\sqrt {ac+c+2}} \leq \frac {3}{2}.$$

I guess that $$\frac {1}{\sqrt {ab+a+2}}+ \frac {1}{\sqrt {bc+b+2}}+ \frac {1}{\sqrt {ac+c+2}} = \frac {3}{2}$$ if and only if $a=b=c=1$. I have spent two nights on this but it's just a mess and I still don't know how to apply Cauchy Schwarz or something to write a rigorous proof for this exercise.

Comment: Have you studied about Cauchy Schwarz? I mean to say this because the square roots and the $\le$ sign pretty much states that Cauchy Schwarz might help here.

Comment: I know that if $x_1,x_2,...,x_n\geq 0$ then $x_1+x_2+...+x_n\geq n\sqrt[n]{x_1x_2...x_n}$, and $\left |x_1y_1+x_2y_2+...+x_ny_n  \right |^2 \leq \left ( \left | x_1 \right |^2 +\left | x_2 \right |^2 +...+\left | x_n \right |^2\right )\left ( \left | y_1 \right |^2 +\left | y_2 \right |^2 +...+\left | y_n \right |^2\right )$. But I don't know how to apply these things.

Comment: Did my answer meet the needs of the given question?

Comment: @Manthanein Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbf {Hint: }$
Let $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab+a+2}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc+b+2}}+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{ac+c+2}}=A$$
Applying C-S: 
$$\left(\frac {1}{ab+a+2}+\frac {1}{bc+b+2}+\frac {1}{ac+c+2}\right)(3) \ge (A)^2$$
Hence $$A\le \sqrt{\left(\frac {1}{ab+a+2}+\frac {1}{bc+b+2}+\frac {1}{ac+c+2}\right)(3)}$$

Now consider by Titu's lemma we have 
$$\frac {1}{ab+1} + \frac {1}{a+1} \ge \frac {4}{ab+a+2}$$
Hence our obtained inequality now has 
$$A\le \sqrt{
\left(
\frac {1}{ab+a+2}+\frac {1}{bc+b+2}+\frac {1}{ac+c+2}
\right)
(3)
}\le 
\sqrt {
\frac{3}{4}
\sum_{cyc} \left(\frac {1}{ab+1} + \frac {1}{a+1}
\right) }$$
But 
$$\sum_{cyc} \left(\frac {1}{ab+1} + \frac {1}{a+1}\right) =\sum_{cyc} \left(\frac {c}{c+1} + \frac {1}{a+1}\right)=3 $$
 Because $abc=1$
Hence 
$$A \le \sqrt {\frac{3}{4} \sum_{cyc} \frac {c}{c+1} + \frac {1}{a+1}}=\sqrt {\frac{9}{4}}=\frac {3}{2}$$

Hope it helped now.

Comment: I know that $\sum ab +\sum a +6 \geq 12$ then I get $t\geq \frac{9}{\sum ab +\sum a +6}$ but $ \frac{9}{\sum ab +\sum a +6} \leq \frac{3}{4}$. How to get $t\leq \frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: Try to use Titu's lemma for $t$

Comment: @Tinh Tran I have now edited the answer please check again

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=\frac{y}{x}$ and $b=\frac{z}{y}$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives.

Thus, $c=\frac{x}{z}$ and by C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab+a+2}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{z}{x}+\frac{y}{x}+2}}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{x}{2x+y+z}}$$
$$\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}1^2\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{2x+y+z}}=\sqrt{3\sum_{cyc}x\cdot\frac{1}{x+z+x+y}}$$
$$\leq\sqrt{3\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{(1+1)^2}\left(\frac{1^2}{x+z}+\frac{1^2}{x+y}\right)}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{x+z}+\frac{x}{x+y}\right)}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{y}{y+x}+\frac{x}{x+y}\right)}=\frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: I think you lost a $3$ in the second expression on the second equation line. I added it in. You can check the edit. You are claiming $\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{x+y+2z}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{2x+y+z}$. That is not correct.

Comment: It was typo. I fixed. Thank you! $\sum\limits_{cyc}1^2=3$. It's correct.

Comment: It was the incessant switching of variable that caused the typo. I edited your answer with the variables sticking to your very first setting. I think it is more conducive to reading this way. I hope you agree. +1 for your answer, as usual.

Comment: Yes. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, I have noticed you continually use the formatting of individual display style equations. I think it is more aesthetically pleasing to use "begin{align} & \\ & end{align}" format. Would you like to try it?